# Accessing a List on demand using SharePoint WebService

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am able to access a Site then Lists inside the Site and then List Items inside all the Lists. This works fine when I want to crawl/access all the Items in a Site.

I am keen to know if there is a way through which we can directly access a List in a Site. To elaborate on this :: If I have 1000 sites and 1000 documents then I would have to go through 1999 items at the worst before finding the one I want.

Any help/suggestion on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using an [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) to get what you need. There are many ways to develop the CAML query you want such as [CAML Query Builder](http://blog.u2u.info/DottextWeb/patrick/archive/2005/05/29/3522.aspx?Pending=true).

This is the best way to avoid trolling through all Webs->Lists->ListItems to find items. 
I prefer to limit the SPSiteDataQuery to one site collection and call the query for each site collection that is relevant as there are some [limitations to the SPSiteDataQuery](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946484).

The equivalent for webservices would be the [GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774532.aspx) in the SiteData webservice

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this doesn't help in scenario where I should be able to do the same ONLY by using the out-of-the-box webservices. I should not use the Microsoft.SharePoint.dll.